# How to change the Python version Jupyter sees?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have Python 3.6 and Python 3.7. In my command prompt, I see:

```
D:\>python --version
Python 3.7.2
```

However, in my Jupyter Notebook, I see:

```
check_python_version()
# prints "Your python version is  3.6.5"
```

Here is what I have in my anaconda directory:

```
03/29/2018  03:36 PM            93,696 python.exe
03/29/2018  03:36 PM           413,696 python.pdb
03/29/2018  03:33 PM            51,200 python3.dll
03/29/2018  03:33 PM         3,603,456 python36.dll
03/29/2018  03:33 PM         9,031,680 python36.pdb
03/29/2018  03:36 PM            92,160 pythonw.exe
```

This is probably a very dumb question, but how do I update Jupyter to see by current Python version?

Thanks.

Comment: There should either be a configuration somewhere, or you run the Jupyter installed for your particular python instead of the default one

Comment: Are you conflating a system Python with a Python installed within a cond environment?

Comment: Apparently. How do I change the Python installed within a cond environment?